# An error has occurred.", ExceptionMessage: "Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided

Tags: c#, .net, reactjs, asp.net-web-api, asp.net-web-api2

Trying to add a file to an http rest call I get this error:

> responseJson = {Message: "An error has occurred.", ExceptionMessage:
>   "Invalid 'HttpContent' instance provided. It does n…rting with
>   'multipart/'. ↵Parameter name: content", ExceptionType:
>   "System.ArgumentException", StackTrace: "   at
>   System.Net.Http.Formatting.Parsers.MimeMulti…tpControllerDispatcher.d__1.MoveNext()"}

my react component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Row, Col } from 'antd';
import PageHeader from '../../components/utility/pageHeader';
import Box from '../../components/utility/box';
import LayoutWrapper from '../../components/utility/layoutWrapper.js';
import ContentHolder from '../../components/utility/contentHolder';
import basicStyle from '../../settings/basicStyle';
import IntlMessages from '../../components/utility/intlMessages';
import { adalApiFetch } from '../../adalConfig';

export default class extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {TenantId: '', TenantUrl: '', TenantPassword: '' };
    this.handleChangeTenantUrl = this.handleChangeTenantUrl.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeTenantPassword = this.handleChangeTenantPassword.bind(this);
    this.handleChangeTenantId= this.handleChangeTenantId.bind(this);
    this.handleSubmit = this.handleSubmit.bind(this);
  };


  handleChangeTenantUrl(event){
    this.setState({TenantUrl: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangeTenantPassword(event){
    this.setState({TenantPassword: event.target.value});
  }

  handleChangeTenantId(event){
    this.setState({TenantId: event.target.value});
  }

  handleSubmit(event){
    event.preventDefault();

    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append("TenantId", this.state.TenantId);
    formData.append("TenantUrl", this.state.TenantUrl);
    formData.append("TenantPassword", this.state.TenantPassword);

    const options = {
      method: 'put',
      data: formData,
      config: {
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'
        }
      }
    };

    adalApiFetch(fetch, "/Tenant", options)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(responseJson => {
        if (!this.isCancelled) {
          this.setState({ data: responseJson });
        }
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.error(error);
      });
  }


  upload(e){
      let data = new FormData();
      //Append files to form data
      let files = e.target.files;
      for (let i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        data.append('files', files[i], files[i].name);
      }      
  }

  render(){
    const { data } = this.state;
    const { rowStyle, colStyle, gutter } = basicStyle;

    return (
      <div>
        <LayoutWrapper>
        <PageHeader>{<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.TenantAdministration" />}</PageHeader>
        <Row style={rowStyle} gutter={gutter} justify="start">
          <Col md={12} sm={12} xs={24} style={colStyle}>
            <Box
              title={<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.TenantAdministration" />}
              subtitle={<IntlMessages id="pageTitles.TenantAdministration" />}
            >
              <ContentHolder>
              <form onSubmit={this.handleSubmit}>
                <label>
                  TenantId:
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.TenantId} onChange={this.handleChangeTenantId} />
                </label>
                <label>
                  TenantUrl:
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.TenantUrl} onChange={this.handleChangeTenantUrl} />
                </label>
                <label>
                  TenantPassword:
                  <input type="text" value={this.state.TenantPassword} onChange={this.handleChangeTenantPassword} />
                </label>
                <label>
                  Certificate:
                  <input onChange = { e => this.upload(e) } type = "file" id = "files" ref = { file => this.fileUpload } />
                </label>             
              <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
              </form>
              </ContentHolder>
            </Box>
          </Col>
        </Row>
      </LayoutWrapper>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

My tenant controller Put method

```
[HttpPut]
        public async Task<IHttpActionResult> PutTenant([FromBody]Tenant tenant)
        {
            var provider = new MultipartMemoryStreamProvider();
            var contentType = "";
            var content = new byte[0];
            await base.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync(provider);
            if (provider.Contents.Count > 0)
            {
                contentType = provider.Contents[0].Headers.ContentType.MediaType;
                content = await provider.Contents[0].ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
            }


            CloudStorageAccount storageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AzureStorageKey"].ToString());
            // Create the blob client.
            CloudBlobClient blobClient = storageAccount.CreateCloudBlobClient();

            // Retrieve reference to a previously created container.
            CloudBlobContainer container = blobClient.GetContainerReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["certificatesContainer"].ToString());

            // Retrieve reference to a blob named "myblob".
            CloudBlockBlob blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference("myblob");

            // Create or overwrite the "myblob" blob with contents from a local file.
            blockBlob.Properties.ContentType = contentType;
            MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(content);
            blockBlob.UploadFromStream(stream);

            var tenantStore = CosmosStoreFactory.CreateForEntity<Tenant>();
            tenant.content = content;
            tenant.CertificatePath = blockBlob.Uri;

            if (!ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                return BadRequest(ModelState);
            }

            var added = await tenantStore.AddAsync(tenant);
            return StatusCode(HttpStatusCode.NoContent); 
        }
```

and the tenant POCO

```
 public class Tenant
    {
        public string TenantId { get; set; }
        public string TenantUrl { get; set; }
        public Uri CertificatePath { get; set; }
        public string CertificatePassword { get; set; }

        public byte[] content { get; set; }

        public override string ToString()
        {
            return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(this);
        }
    }
```

stacktrace:

```
"   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.Parsers.MimeMultipartBodyPartParser.ValidateArguments(HttpContent content, Int64 maxMessageSize, Boolean throwOnError)
   at System.Net.Http.Formatting.Parsers.MimeMultipartBodyPartParser..ctor(HttpContent content, MultipartStreamProvider streamProvider, Int64 maxMessageSize, Int32 maxBodyPartHeaderSize)
   at System.Net.Http.HttpContentMultipartExtensions.<ReadAsMultipartAsync>d__0`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter`1.GetResult()
   at TenantManagementWebApi.Controllers.TenantController.<PutTenant>d__2.MoveNext() in C:\Users\levm3\source\repos\TenantManagementWebApi\Controllers\TenantController.cs:line 48
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Threading.Tasks.TaskHelpersExtensions.<CastToObject>d__3`1.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ApiControllerActionInvoker.<InvokeActionAsyncCore>d__0.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Controllers.ActionFilterResult.<ExecuteAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Filters.AuthorizationFilterAttribute.<ExecuteAuthorizationFilterAsyncCore>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Web.Http.Dispatcher.HttpControllerDispatcher.<SendAsync>d__1.MoveNext()"
```

Update 1:

When I attach the debugger remotely the tenant parameter is null, so something must be wrong when setting the parameters on the client component.

Comment: Can you post entire stack trace, that 'll help to understand who is complaining about content type.

Comment: I posted the stacktrace, I also attached the debugger and what I can see is that tenant is null, no parameters are received.

Comment: Try removing content-type header from put method call in the react component.

Comment: the tenant parameter in the controller is null when I attach the debugger

Comment: Use chrome to find out what exactly are you sending from the JS and try to send same info from postman and see if asp.net can read Tenant. Also, I see upload method in js stores data for FormData which is not preserved.

Comment: I dont see anything sent, why? https://screencast.com/t/qR8BR72AM

Comment: May be: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6974684/how-to-send-formdata-objects-with-ajax-requests-in-jquery

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess your `[FromBody]Tenant tenant` is null because you use `multipart/form-data`.

The default model binder can not resolve your model in this case.

Please review example from Microsoft [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2) (section [Reading Form Control Data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2#reading-form-control-data)).

You need to read your model data using `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider`. As I can see you use the provider only for file content reading. But also you can read your model data (like TenantId, TenantUrl, etc) from `FormData` property.

As second (and more general) approach you can create your own [IModelBinder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/en-us/library/system.web.modelbinding.imodelbinder(v=vs.110).aspx) implementation.

Here you can review example of my implementation of IModelBinder (It is code from real project):

```
public class NativeTranslateModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
    public bool BindModel(HttpActionContext actionContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        if (bindingContext.ModelType != typeof(NativeTranslateViewModel))
        {
            return false;
        }

        var task = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            var model = new NativeTranslateViewModel();

            if (!actionContext.Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent())
            {
                bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "WebRequeest content 'multipart/form-data' is valid");
            }
            else
            {
                var provider = await actionContext.Request.Content.ReadAsMultipartAsync();

                var fileContent = provider.Contents.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Equals("file"));
                if (fileContent == null)
                {
                    bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Section 'file' is missed");
                }

                var modelContent = provider.Contents.FirstOrDefault(n => n.Headers.ContentDisposition.Name.Equals("model"));
                if (modelContent == null)
                {
                    bindingContext.ModelState.AddModelError(bindingContext.ModelName, "Section 'model' is missed");
                }

                if (fileContent != null && modelContent != null)
                {
                    model = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<NativeTranslateViewModel>(await modelContent.ReadAsStringAsync());
                    model.Text = "<NativeTranslation>";
                    model.FileData = await fileContent.ReadAsByteArrayAsync();
                    model.FileName = fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition.FileName;
                }
            }

            return model;
        });

        task.Wait();

        bindingContext.Model = task.Result;
        return true;
    }
}
```

We can use new model binder very easy:

```
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage UploadNativeDocument([ModelBinder(typeof(NativeTranslateModelBinder))] NativeTranslateViewModel model)
```

Now we can use our model and model properties inside controller action.

Comment: so I dont need to change my react code, my problem is in the web api only, I thought I was sending the parameters wrong

Comment: I think you have a trouble with web api. Review documentation link from my answer. Just try to read all model properties using `MultipartFormDataStreamProvider`.

Comment: then I would need a custom ModelBinder each time I have a form with a file? for standard forms I dont need a model binder right?

Comment: You can implement model binder only for `multipart/form-data` requests. If you send only form you can send JSON or Form. In this case you do not need ModelBinder. Example for sending form is [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-1)

Comment: @Alexamder, I did exactly as you said, but actionContext.Request.Content.IsMimeMultipartContent() is false,

Comment: please check this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51427280/modelbinder-ismultipartcontent-always-returning-false-how-to-upload-file-with-r

Comment: your code has helped, however I am still struggling, can u see this one: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51430809/webapi-how-to-read-the-file-from-a-post-put-action-with-custom-model-binder

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you it doesn't like the way you formatted the data. From experience, C# MVC and API does not like form data. I would change your content type to 'application/json', then send the data like below:

```
data:{"TenantId": this.state.TenantId, "TenantUrl": this.state.TenantUrl, "TenantPassword": this.state.TenantPassword }
```

Also, double check that if the table you're inserting into contains any not null fields, those fields are not null when you perform the insert.

Comment: are you sure this will work? application/json? I am also sending a fileupload.

Comment: this answer is not valid, it doesnt work, I tried changing the contenttype, and then the error says its expectint multiform/data because I am expecting a file upload. I do changed data as you said.

Comment: You'd need to change your React side to also construct a json message with the file upload data in it, likely needing to be base64 encoded which would increase the payload size somewhat

Answer (score 1):

WebApi doesn't support FormMultipart data very well, you need to basically parse it manually: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28462699/356218

I thought I recalled having to register handlers for `multipart/form-data` so that your server even knows it can *try* to handle that datatype, but the above as well as https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/advanced/sending-html-form-data-part-2 (pretty similar to the above link) doesn't seem to mention that